# Leaving pictures as RGB in a pdf sent for a commercial printer, and setting color management in indd

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production, color-profile

Background: I did a PDF for a commercial printer and got a test proof print, which was OK. The final print product looked different, the colors where darker and more saturated. This difference was probably cause the proof might be digitally printed and only simulates the end profile, and the actual product is offset printed.

I’d like to troubleshoot is there a fault in my workflow or was there a mistake in the printers end that might explain this.

My indesign uses Fogra39 as working profile. The printer uses PSO coated V3. I didn’t change my working profile, but I did a new empty file and converted the profile of the file using “convert profile” command to PSO coated 3. After this did I did the layout.  The instruction is to leave RGB pictures not converted. I exported the PDF using settings downloaded from the printer. In their output settings, there is no colour conversion and they include all profiles.

Doing  the PDF like this, when you open it in Acrobat and inspect an object, it says the Blending colour space is PSO coated and picture profile is an RGB profile (depending on the pic,  might be sRGB or adobe RGB). Preview with Acrobat through PSO is fine, but the actual printed document looked different (keeping in mind sceen/print differences of course).

Do you recognize any faults in the process? I have tried to contact the press to troubleshoot, but I haven’t gotten this sorted out yet.

Comment: Was the same file used for the proof & final print? If so, it's their fault, no matter what else may have happened. If they can't repro their own proof, who else can??

Comment: Yes the same file was the source for the PDFs. But what about we assume that there never was a proof, i'd still like to find out was there a fault in my end to avoid this happening in the future.

Comment: They have two different paths from PDF to printed image. One works, the other doesn't. I don't see how you can investigate from your end why that is true.

Comment: If the problem is in their end, it is true I can't. But if there is a fault in my settings or workflow, that i'd like to detect :)

Comment: if they can produce two results from on file...

Comment: That your working profile is set to FOGRA39 doesn't matter when you have converted your document to another profile, so you can rule that out. And also since the images in your PDF still have their original RGB profile, the CMYK profile of the document doesn't really influence the images. Leaving the images as RGB leaves it to the print house to convert the images to CMYK and it seems that something goes wrong there. Perhaps the digital proof weren't converted properly to CMYK or the wrong profile was simulated. Or perhaps it goes wrong in the RIP for offset. We can't know.

Comment: Also would be nice to see the difference between the two prints and your digital preview. Hard to tell how big the difference is just by your description.

Comment: Thanks, that conversion to a different profile than the working profile was one of which I was unsure of. 

The difference between the proof and the actual print was noticeable. Much darker dark areas and a bit oversaturated colors. The proof was a bit more soft with contrasts. The result if you would have never seen the proof ”acceptable” but not similar to the proof.

Comment: And i misread your question: the proof and digital preview where a closer match than the actual product.

Comment: I think the focus is too much here on your workflow: as @Tetsujin has stated: you received 2 hard-copies from your file and they were different. This is the printer's problem and not yours. You cannot fix this. Further, the printer's proof is a proof for everything: any deviation from the approved proof is a breach of contract, basically.

Comment: @Yorik That depends entirely on what _kind_ of proof they provide. “Test proof print” is rather a vague term, and it’s not clear whether the first proof received was a colour/press proof or a prepress proof, which does not guarantee correct colours (in fact almost guarantees incorrect colours). If the document is a book, you’d normally get a plotter proof before going to print; and if you don’t know that you have to create a photo sheet for a separate colour/press proof specifically to verify image colours, you might be misled to believe the colours in your plotter proof are accurate.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I certainly agree that there are instances where the printer may provide a different type of hard-copy proof, but that does not appear to be the case here. In every circumstance where a proof was taken for a lower standard, the printer took great pains to specify this, and my approvals of such proofs were always explicit about what was being approved. I admittedly haven't done any books larger than c. 120 pages, but they have all been color spreads w/fully-imposed color-accurate proofs. We haven't pulled a "randoms" proof for color since we stopped paste-up of "randoms"

Comment: @Yorik That must vary a lot by place, then. I don’t think any printers here even _offer_ colour proofs unless you specifically ask for it (and you’ll pay for it!). All content proofs we receive these days are either soft proofs (PDF) or plotter proofs, and then we decide whether we want a proof sheet or not for a given book. Most of our books are in the 300–800 page range, but I don’t think the routine is any different for smaller books. The printers don’t inform us that plotter proofs aren’t colour-accurate, but presumably that’s because they know we’re well aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the essence of this question is about the proof being different than the final product and what you can do to fix that. As Tetsujin suggested, you cannot fix what is essentially the printer's problem.

So far as your *electronic* workflow question, I am not convinced you *have* a workflow problem: you cannot know if your workflow is causing issues without looking at *printer-attested accurate* proof.

However as JanusBahsJacquet suggested, you may have received a proof that was not meant to be color-accurate, and that in their experience, printers tend to be more loose with proofs: proofs for color vs. proofs for glyph drop-out/compositing issues etc., so (my leaving aside my simplistic comment above) it may not be that big a deal as long as you are clear about what you are getting when presented with a hard-copy proof.

So this is "workflow question" in an expanded sense: ask for the proof you need and approve the proof you get *for the purpose it was intended*. If you are not evaluating color: indicate that you are not evaluating color in your clear communication to the printer's representative.

My work involves accurate reproduction of images of fine-art objects and so color-accurate printing is more important than anything else. For that reason, not seeing an actual color-accurate proof that is promised to match what comes off the press is a 10s-of-thousands-of-dollars mistake. Then again, if I am submitting a 1-page PDF to a "magazine format" or other type of "mixed submission catalog," I usually just check the JPG and approve: I trust my own workflow (based on hard-copy color-accurate proofing) and magazines tend to not hold color anyway (so many full-pages imposed together with wildly different full-page saturated color) and we need to learn to [Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove).

I suppose the answer is to insist on *some form* of color-accurate proof that the printer asserts they can match on press. This might be large sheets of the book fully imposed or they might be some reasonable sub-sample which you submit to "spot check." This will allow you to be more confident that the truckload of books you just had delivered on your employer's dime will meet your expectations for quality.